# Summarise in dplyr for R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dplyr table:

```
> movies
Source: local data frame [250 x 3]

                                            name   year rating
                                          (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)
1                       The Shawshank Redemption   1994    9.2
2                                  The Godfather   1972    9.2
3                         The Godfather: Part II   1974      9
4                                The Dark Knight   2008    8.9
...
```

I want to do some basic analysis using summarise.  when I enter something like:

```
summarise(movies,count = sum(rating))
```

I get:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(12L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,  : 
‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

So - I've been trying to change 'rating' from a factor to a numeric.  I've tried

```
as.numeric(as.character(movies$rating))
```

and

```
transform(movies, rating = as.numeric(rating))
```

But neither seem to work.  I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.  Do I need to change the factor to an integer?  I'm assuming I do.  How can I get this done?

Comment: Try `movies %>% summarise(count= sum(as.numeric(as.character(rating))))`

Comment: Did you assign it? `movies$rating <- as.numeric(as.character(movies$rating))` changes the column to numeric then you can run `summarise`

Comment: Richard:  I'm an idiot.  That was my problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R error "sum not meaningful for factors"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045096/r-error-sum-not-meaningful-for-factors)