# Adding a column to a data frame using mutate in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dplyr

I am working with `OJ`data set in ISLR package. I need to add to columns to the data frame. One column is a product of two numerical variable. The second column is a product of numerical and categorical variables .

I added the first column (numerical*numerical) using `mutate` function in `dplyr` package in R as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
OJ %>% 
  mutate(`StoreID:PriceCH` = StoreID*PriceCH)
```

And i was able to add this coulmn sucessfully. But when i tried to do the same when adding the categorical*numeric column i am getting an error.

```
OJ %>% 
  mutate(`Store7:PriceCH` = Store7*PriceCH)

Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Store7, PriceCH) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

Can anyone suggest what i can do if i need to add coulmn which is a product of categorical*numerical ?

My output should be something like this,

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R error "sum not meaningful for factors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045096/r-error-sum-not-meaningful-for-factors)

Comment: I didnt use images to show the data. I used the image to show my expected output .

Comment: What do you intend to do to turn a categorical variable into numeric, or otherwise multiply something by a category?

Answer (score 0):

Apply one-hot encoding to `Store7` first:

```
OJ <- cbind(OJ, sapply("Yes", function(x) as.integer(x == OJ$Store7)))
names(OJ)[ncol(OJ)] <- "Store7_Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, I does not make a lot of sense (in most of the cases) multiply categorical variables.

Thought if you want to do so, you have to transform your data to a numeric scale. Be aware that this is not always so straightfoward.

This could be a starting point:

```
library(tidyverse)

Result <- OJ %>% 
  mutate(`StoreID:PriceCH` = StoreID*PriceCH) %>% 
  mutate(Store7Numeric = as.character(Store7)) #To avoid possible mistakes

Result <- Result %>% 
  mutate(Store7Numeric = ifelse(Store7Numeric == "No", 0, 1)) #Check this

Result <- Result %>% mutate(Store7Numeric = as.numeric(Store7Numeric)) %>% #To numeric
mutate(`Store7:PriceCH` = Store7Numeric*PriceCH) %>% #Your calculation
select(-Store7Numeric) #Remove, if you want. the created numeric variable
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to variable `Store7` being a `factor` (See in `str(OJ)`), so you must make it `numeric`:

```r
OJ$Store7 <- as.numeric(OJ$Store7)
```